# How is decision boundary for ensemble methods/decision tree generated in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, decision-tree

Decision Trees work by splitting the training subsets at every node iterating through root to leaf nodes till we get our classification/regression result.

But how is the actual **decision boundary(weights)** calculated? We use the cost function to perform the split at every node. Does this cost function also help us to find weights?

For example, to build an AdaBoost classifier, a first base classifier (such as a Decision Tree) is trained and used to make predictions on the training set. The *relative weight* of misclassified training instances is then increased. A second classifier is trained using the updated weights and again it makes predictions on the training set, weights are updated, and so on.

How is this **Relative weight** calculated?

Answer (score 1):

In Adaboosting the relative weights are calculated as follows,

First, given `m` number of training instances, every instance is given an equal weight of 1/m.

Now we define the weighted error rate of the jth predictor/classifier after training as follows:

r(j) = sum(incorrect instance's weights) / sum(all instance's weights)

Now we define another term, the predictor/classifier's weight as follows :

cw(j) = learning rate * log ( (1 - r(j))/(rj) )

Now to the **relative weights** of each instance, we calculate them as follows, where i is the instance's index/identifier:

if w(i) was correctly classified in the last predictor, then :

w(i) = w(i)

else if w(i) was incorrectly classified, then :

w(i) = w(i) * exp(cw(j))

This would increase the weights of misclassified instances if they are less than 50% of the instances, if the last predictor classified 50% of the instance's correct, this would set r(j) = .5, which leads to cw(j) = 0, and w(i) for the incorrect instances would be w(i) * 1, which means no changes in the incorrect instances weights.

Comment: This was pretty hard to write without latex, so please let me know if you require any further explaination @Shamika